# uploadFiles angularjs function, data not found during AJAX call

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am using the following angularJS function to upload images to my site,

```
.controller('fupController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

        var formdata = new FormData();

        $scope.getTheFiles = function ($files) {

            $scope.imagesrc = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.fileName = $files[i].name;


                reader.onload = function (event) {

                    var image = {};
                    image.Name = event.target.fileName;
                    image.Size = (event.total / 1024).toFixed(2);
                    image.Src = event.target.result;
                    $scope.imagesrc.push(image);
                    $scope.$apply();
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL($files[i]);


            }

            angular.forEach($files, function (value, key) {
                formdata.append(key, value);  

            })


        }

        $scope.uploadFiles = function () {
            var request = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:61194/api/FileUpload',
                //data: formdata,
                //data: { gallery: $scope.galleries[$scope.index].Id },
                file: File,

                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': undefined
                }
            };

            $http(request).success(function (d) {
                alert(d);
                $scope.reset();


            }).error(function () {
                alert("Failed");
                $scope.reset();

            })

        }

        $scope.reset = function () {
            angular.forEach(
                angular.element("input [type = 'file']"),
                function (inputElem) {
                    angular.element(inputElem).val(null);
                }
                );


            $scope.imagesrc = [];
            formdata = new FormData();

        }

    }])
```

the full code of the angular html template is as below:

```
<section class="view">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="goBack()">Back</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <img class="contact-img" ng-src="{{contact.imageUrl}}">
    <section>
        <article>
            <div class="contact-card">
                <h3 class="text-center">{{contact.firstName}} {{contact.lastName}}</h3>
                <h6 class="text-center">{{contact.emailAddress}}</h6>
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
</div>
<form class="form margin-top-small" name="contactForm">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="first-name">Picture</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <!--<input type="text" class="form-control input-large" required id="Picture" placeholder="Enter image Url" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files)" ng-model="contact.imageUrl">-->
                <!--<input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this)" />-->
                <!--<div ng-controller="fupController">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="uploadFiles()" value="Upload" />
                </div>-->

                <div ng-controller="fupController">

                    <div class="container">

                        <div class="panel panel-info">

                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                Photos
                            </div>

                            <div class="panel-body">

                                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>title</td>
                                            <td>Image</td>
                                            <td>Size</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr ng-repeat="image in imagesrc track by $index">
                                            <td>{{image.Name}}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <img ng-src="{{image.Src}}" title="{{image.Title}}" style="width: 100px;" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>{{image.Size}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                                        <input type="file" multipe ng-files="getTheFiles($files)" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                                        <input ng-disabled="!imagesrc.length" type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="uploadFiles()" value="Upload" />
                                        <input ng-disabled="!imagesrc.length" type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="reset()" value="Cancel" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <!--<input type="file" file-model="myFile" />
                <button ng-click="uploadFile()">upload me</button>

                <!-- FILE UPLOAD WITH PREVIEW, NEED TO ENABLE THE JAVASCRIPT BELOW  -->
                <!--<input type="file" id="imagess" onchange="previewFile()" ng-model="contact.imageUrl"><br>-->
                <!--FILE UPLOAD 1-->
                <!--<input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files)" />-->
                <!--FILE UPLOAD 2-->
                <!--<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
                    <input type="file" ngf-select="onFileSelect($files)" multiple>
                </div>-->
                <!--FILE UPLOAD 3-->
                <!--<div ng-controller="fileuploadCtrl">
                    <input type="file" ng-file-select name="file" ng-file-change="upload($files)">
                        <div class="progress" style=" margin 0%">
                            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" ng-style="{ 'width': percentComplete + '%' }" style="width: 0%;">
                                <span ng-if="percentComplete === 100">{{items.attachment}} upload completed successfully</span>
                            </div>
                                <span ng-if="percentComplete > 0" class="fileupload">{{percentComplete}}%</span>
                        </div>
                </div>-->
                <!--FILE UPLOAD 4-->
                <!--<div ng-controller="fileuploadCtrl">
                <input type="file" ngf-select="upload($files)" multiple>
                </div>-->
                <!--FILE UPLOAD 5-->
                <!--<div ng-controller="MyCtrl2">
                    <h4>Upload on file select</h4>
                    <button type="file" ngf-select="uploadFiles($file, $invalidFiles)"
                            accept="image/*" ngf-max-height="1000" ngf-max-size="1MB">
                        Select File
                    </button>
                    <br><br>
                    File:
                    <div style="font:smaller">
                        {{f.name}} {{errFile.name}} {{errFile.$error}} {{errFile.$errorParam}}
                        <span class="progress" ng-show="f.progress >= 0">
                            <div style="width:{{f.progress}}%"
                                 ng-bind="f.progress + '%'"></div>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    {{errorMsg}}
                </div>-->
                <!--FILE UPLOAD 6-->
                <!--<div ng-controller="MyCtrl2">
                <input type="file" ngf-select="uploadFiles($file, $invalidFiles)" multiple>
                </div>-->
                <!--<img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">-->
                <!--<input type="file" id="multi_file_upload" ng-model="contact.imageUrl"><br>
                <img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="first-name">First Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-large" required id="first-name" placeholder="Enter first name" ng-model="contact.firstName">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="last-name">Last Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-large" required id="last-name" placeholder="Enter last name" ng-model="contact.lastName">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="email-address">Email</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-large" required ng-pattern="{{regularExpressions.emailAddress}}" id="email-address" placeholder="Enter email address" ng-model="contact.emailAddress">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group margin-top-small">
            <div class="controls">
                <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" ng-click="save(contact, contactForm)">Save Contact</button>-->
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" ng-click="save(contact, contactForm)">Save Contact</button>
                <span class="alert alert-info" ng-show="hasSaved">
                    <strong>Confirmation: </strong>contact saved ! <br>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                </span>
                <span class="alert alert-info" ng-show="saveError">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                    <strong>Failed: </strong>contact not saved ! <br>
                </span>
                <p>{{errortext}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

This is the Index page and the scripts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title>CSS Black Book</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="src/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="src/css/Flip.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>
<body>

    <header data-ng-controller="HeaderController">
        <nav class="navbar">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/contacts">CSS Black Book</a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li ng-class="{active: routeIs('contacts')}"><a href="#/contact">Contacts</a></li>
                <li ng-class="{active: routeIs('about')}"><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div data-ng-view data-ng-animate="{enter: 'view-enter', leave: 'view-leave'}"></div>    


    <script src="lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    

    <!--<script src="lib/angular/ng-file-upload-shim.min.js"></script>-->  <!-- for no html5 browsers support -->
    <script src="../node_modules/ng-file-upload/dist/ng-file-upload-shim.min.js"></script>


    <!--<script src="../../Scripts/angular.js"></script>-->
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>


    <!--<script src="lib/angular/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="../node_modules/ng-file-upload/dist/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script>



    <script src="lib/angular/angular.resource.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="../Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>-->

    <script src="src/common/resources/contacts.js"></script>
    <script src="src/common/resources/lookups.js"></script>
    <script src="src/common/services/config.js"></script>
    <script src="src/common/services/state.js"></script>
    <script src="src/common/directives/mouse-enter-css.js"></script>
    <script src="src/common/directives/mouse-leave-css.js"></script>
    <script src="src/common/services/config.js"></script>
    <script src="src/app/contacts/contacts.js"></script>
    <script src="src/app/about/about.js"></script>
    <script src="src/app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/respond/respond.min.js"></script>  


    <!--<script src="../../Scripts/angular.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script src="../../site/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script src="../../site/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script src="../App2/file-upload.js"></script>-->


</body>
</html>
```

Here is the controller that gets called to do the actual upload of the image to a project folder called "Gallery":

```
public class FileUploadController : ApiController
{


    private FileUploadDemoDbContext Context = new FileUploadDemoDbContext();


    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    [HttpRoute("api/FileUpload")]
    public IHttpActionResult Upload()
    {
        int uploadCount = 0;

        string sPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/Gallery/");

        System.Web.HttpFileCollection files = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;

        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
        {

            System.Web.HttpPostedFile file = files[i];

            string fileName = new FileInfo(file.FileName).Name;

            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                //Guid id = new Guid();
                Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

                string modifiedFileName = id.ToString() + "_" + fileName;

                if (!File.Exists(sPath + Path.GetFileName(modifiedFileName)))
                {

                    file.SaveAs(sPath + Path.GetFileName(modifiedFileName));
                    uploadCount++;

                    //Context.Galleries.Add(new Gallery() { Id = Convert.ToInt32(id.ToString()), FileName = "/Gallery" + modifiedFileName, Title = fileName });

                    Context.Galleries.Add(new Gallery() { Id = id, FileName = "/Gallery" + modifiedFileName, Title = fileName });

                }

            }

        }


        if (uploadCount > 0)
        {
            Context.SaveChanges();
            return Ok("Uploaded Successfully");

        }
        return InternalServerError();

    }


    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {

        if (disposing)
        {
            Context.Dispose();

        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

}
```

Issue I am having is that no file is sent to the controller... I can actually see that the image is uploaded on the page though as this is the first step of the download, its sort of a preview of the image before user clicks on the Upload button. The interesting part is that if I make the call from a different html document, one with the structure below, the AJAX Post call does succeed and the file is uploaded successfully !!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="../../site/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
    <script src="../../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../../site/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../site/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../App2/file-upload.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="fupApp" ng-controller="fupController">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="panel panel-info">

            <div class="panel-heading">
                Photos
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">

                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>title</td>
                            <td>Image</td>
                            <td>Size</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="image in imagesrc track by $index">
                            <td>{{image.Name}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <img ng-src="{{image.Src}}" title="{{image.Title}}" style="width: 100px;"/>                            
                            </td>
                            <td>{{image.Size}}</td>
                        </tr> 
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-7">
                            <input type="file" multipe ng-files="getTheFiles($files)" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-5">
                            <input ng-disabled="!imagesrc.length" type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="uploadFiles()" value="Upload" />
                            <input ng-disabled="!imagesrc.length" type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="reset()" value="Cancel" />
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Have tried to change the way the data is sent like below with no joy...

data: formdata
data: [gallery: $scope.galleries[$scope.index].Id]
data: file

Another possible reason could be the scripts I use as they are different on both templates...

Any suggestions ?? many thanks

Comment: If you want to pass multiple files then you need to use indexing on the key like this formdata.append('[' + i + '].' + key, value);

Comment: Thanks abdul but I am fine uploading only one file at a time and it does work when I make the upload from the second html template, I just want to get it working on the first template